# Redshift Column Level Encryption and Decryption

Tags: encryption, amazon-redshift

I want to load data (few encrypted fields) into Redshift and few users should have access to decrypt those encrypted fields. Please suggest the best approach to achieve the result.

I tried the below python udf but it did not work.
[Redshift Python encrypt/decrypt UDF Error - String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662456/redshift-python-encrypt-decrypt-udf-error-string-contains-invalid-or-unsupport)

How should we enable to encryption/decryption at column/field level in Redshift

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to secure the data by encrypting the data, you would need a way to pass the encryption key with the query, otherwise anybody with permissions to use the UDF could decrypt the data by simply calling the Decrypt UDF. Such encryption is only useful if you wish to enforce *encryption at rest*, which is easier done by configuring Redshift to encrypt all data at rest. (Note that this can have a performance impact.)

The recommended method of controlling access to columns is to restrict access to the underlying table, but grant access to a `VIEW` that contains only the permitted columns:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT col1, col3 from my_table;
GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO GROUP restricted_group;
REVOKE ALL ON my_table FROM GROUP restricted_group;
```

Comment: Thanks John. We thought of controlling access to UDF by giving access only specific users and others can see only encrypted data. In any case, we do not want to store the data on Redshift in decrypted format (i.e. actual data) hence planned to use UDF. Please advise.

Comment: Is the intent of the encryption to "encrypt at rest" to reduce the threat of evil operators accessing your data out-of-channel (in which case, Redshift offers this option), or is the intent to restrict access to data from users within your own organization? If the latter, then restricting access to tables and views is just as effective as restricting access to a UDF. Also, encrypting data within columns means that performance will be extremely bad — it will completely ruin the efficiency on that column for sorting, grouping, WHERE, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per our data security team, we should not store the real secure data on Redshift for long time and they did not approve the views concept hence we moved to UDF option. Could you please take a look at these links and suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662456/redshift-python-encrypt-decrypt-udf-error-string-contains-invalid-or-unsupport     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735127/redshift-udf-aes-encrypt-no-module-named-crypto-cipher-mode-ecb

Comment: The security of the Python function is the same as the security of the table/view. They both use the same `GRANT` method of access. Your Data Security Team should familiarise themselves with the [security capabilities of Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_security-overview.html). The UDF is less secure because it actually contains the encryption key.

Comment: Yes I agree. They want to control the access at UDF level instead of tabel level