# Redshift UDF AES ENCRYPT - No module named Crypto.Cipher._mode_ecb

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

**LIBRARY**

```
create library pycryptodome
language plpythonu
from 's3://aws_python/library/pycryptodome/pycryptodome.zip'
credentials 'aws_iam_role'
region as 'aws-region';
```

**FUNCTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.aes_encrypt(input varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
STABLE
AS 
'
    if input is None:
       return None
    import pycryptodome
    encrypt=True
    secret_key = b''abcdefghijklmnop''
    remainder = len(secret_key) % 16
    modified_key = secret_key.ljust(len(secret_key) + (16 - remainder))[:32]
    remainder = len(input) % 16
    modified_text = input.ljust(len(input) + (16 - remainder))
    cipher = pycryptodome.AES.new(modified_key, pycryptodome.AES.MODE_ECB)
    return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(modified_text)).strip()
'
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I have tested this code in python and it worked correctly.
Here function created successfully but when i use function test.aes_encrypt as 
select test.aes_encrypt('testing') then its throwing error:

> No module named Crypto.Cipher._mode_ecb.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need import pycryptodome with `import Crypto`

Comment: I tried `import Crypto` but it did not work. 
**Error** 
`nvalid operation: OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.so': /rdsdbdata/user_lib/1/0/12345.zip/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.so: cannot open shared object file: Not a directory, 
Trying '_raw_ecbmodule.so': `  
Please advise 
 Here is the library module 
 Folder - pycryptodome:
Folder - Crypto
__init__
Folder - Cipher 
AES 
_mode_ecb

Answer (score 0):

Redshift UDF expects you to store the zip file in a specific structure -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

```
geometry/
   __init__.py
   trig/
      __init__.py
      line.py
```

And it can only import .py files - so pure python libraries have to be added to your .zip file, if you are trying to import a .py file which in turn imports non-python files in the package, it can throw this error